# UTF-8 encoded String from Android in JSON to Python Flask via HTTP post

Tags: android, python, json, flask, encoding

I'm a bit clueless about this.

I try to send a JSON object from an Android client to my Python Flask server.
I send it the following way:

```
System.out.println("Building the http request");
            URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.home_server_url_send_records));
            SendTracksObject sendTracksObject = buildRecordsJson();
            JSONArray listOfRecords = sendTracksObject.listOfRecordsJsonArray;
            JSONObject sendToServerObject = new JSONObject();
            sendToServerObject.put("Track_History", listOfRecords);

            System.out.println("Sending: " + sendToServerObject.toString());
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement je = jp.parse(sendToServerObject.toString());
            String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
            System.out.println(prettyJsonString);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(sendToServerObject.toString());

            os.flush();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String responseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            System.out.println(responseCode + ": " + responseMessage);
            conn.disconnect;
```

This works for most of the things I am trying to send, however as soon as a character that's not ASCII, like é or ð is in there, I get a 400 error before the server even tries to decipher what's in there. I suppose this is because the encoding messes with the structure of the request and Flask has no idea how to interpret the result. Funnily, when I use PostMan to send the exact same request, it works.

How can I ensure that the encoding for the String I am trying to send does not mess with Flask?

Answer (score 0):

try to write bytes (with UTF-8) instead of a String in DataOutputStream, like:

```
byte[] data = sendToServerObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.writeInt(data.length);
os.write(data);
...
```

Comment: I assume you meant "sendToServerObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"). That unfortunately does not work either.